# Sending email from R and Python: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: python, r, email

I am trying to send an email through my office email.  It was working for a few months last summer then stopped for no reason.  I am trying through both R and Python (just to double-check that it wasn't a language specific issue) and both have failed using simple programs.

I have tried both R and Python Programs.

The R code is:

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "<my MSoffice email>"
recipients <- c("<my MSoffice email>")
send.mail(from = sender,
      to = recipients,
      subject = "Example",
      body = "Example",
      authenticate = TRUE,
      smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.office365.com", port = 587, 
                  user.name = "<my MSOffice email>",            
                  passwd = "<my MSOffice password>", tls=TRUE))
```

The Python code is:

```
import smtplib
mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.login('<my MSOffice email>, '<my MSOffice password>')
mailserver.sendmail('<my MSOffice email>','<my MSOffice email>','python email')
mailserver.quit()
```

Both programs fail with "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful"

Answer (score 0):

For the python example, when using `starttls`, I think you need `mailserver.ehlo()` (again) after `mailserver.starttls()`.

```
import smtplib
mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.ehlo()  #again
mailserver.login('<my MSOffice email>', '<my MSOffice password>')
mailserver.sendmail('<my MSOffice email>','<my MSOffice email>','python email')
mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried this but still same error.  I think it might be some server side security they put in place for our company.

Comment: Can you authenticate with smtp.office365.com using a standard mail client (like Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.), using the same credentials that you're using in your script?

Comment: I can connect using Outlook on a company computer.  But I tried using Evolution on a personal computer and it would not work, even with correct server settings.

Comment: In both cases, were you connecting to smtp.office365.com on port 587 and using STARTTLS?

Comment: Well I only had to use R initially since it just worked.  And yes the code was exactly the same.